# What is the ancient Egyptian term for 'tomb raiders'?

Tags: language, ancient-egypt

I couldn't find the answer for this on the internet. I am currently writing a fiction story about mummies and this info is crucial.

Comment: Please let us know where you have looked so that others here avoid wasting time duplicating your research. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure we'd necessarily have the skills here to answer everyday vocabulary questions about any and all ancient languages that ever existed.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure they would call them specifically tomb raiders as opposed to just thieves or something similar.

Comment: Here's a dictionary of middle Egyptian with two words for "thief". I'm sure there are other such dictionaries you can look at. https://pyramidtextsonline.com/documents/DicksonDictionary.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

justCal's answer can be expanded on. The Book [T.E. Peet's The Great Tomb Robberies of the Twentieth Egyptian Dynasty](https://archive.org/details/THEGREATTOMBROBBERIESOFTHETWENTIETHEGYPTIANDYNASTY/page/n49/mode/2up) contains on page 38 the translation of page 3 of the Abbot papyrus. In its first paragraph, the word "thieves" appears three times, in lines 2, 5 and 7. In the hig-res [photograph](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/Y_EA10221-1) from the British Museum, that page is the leftmost column, and you can actually find the same sequence of graphemes in all these lines:

[image]

Hieratic is written right-to-left with sometimes graphemes positioned on top of each other. My transcription using [Gardiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gardiner%27s_sign_list) identifiers would go like this:

- ligature of two graphemes, not identified
- [`M17`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/11701)
- [`G1`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/10551)
- [`G47`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/10854)
- upper part: vertical ligature of `D51` + `D40`
- lower part: [`A1`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/5069)
- [`Z3A`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/38614)

The project AKU-PAL can filter its database of hieratic grapheme samples to those of the [correct period](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/graphemes#dating=Neues%20Reich%2C%2020.%20Dynastie&id=350). Some of the samples are actually taken from that papyrus, and are originally documented by [Georg Möller, Hieratische Paläographie](http://ancientworldonline.blogspot.com/2014/02/mollers-hieratische-palaographie-online.html), vol. 2. All the links in the above list are from that source.

The dictionary entries in justCal's answer have mostly the sequence `A24 A1`, which seem to stand for "a person forcing something". That might be a hint for the two graphemes ordered vertically, where the lower one is relatively clearly `A1`. But the upper one is not [`A24`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/5033) as identified by Möller. Instead, in his numbering as  118B, it can be seen on p. 10 (p.28 of this [PDF](http://www.egyptology.ru/lang/Moeller/Moeller-II-1-30.pdf)). In the second last column the position in the papyrus is identified as column 3, line 5, which can only be in the highlighted word. There seems to be no database entry for that in AKU-PAL, but if you look at the [Thot sign list](https://thotsignlist.org/mysign?id=2318), you find that vertical combination as the sematic value "taking".

[image]

The last grapheme indicates a plural, without it it would be "thief", singular.

If you ignore that first ligature, I would say the correlation to **áthau** is relatively convincing.

---

Peet has a lot to say about contextual differences for the word "tomb" throughout his book. But one variant can be identified in a comparable manner. Column 2 line 1 of the papyrus is translated by Peet as

> The pyramids, graves and **tombs** examined this day by the inspectors.

That line contains three consecutive sequences ending with the plural sign. The third looks like this:

[image]

The same word appears at the start of line 1 of column 4 ([next photo in the British Museum repo](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/Y_EA10221-2), top right corner).

[image]

This gives an important hint, because [Peet](https://archive.org/details/THEGREATTOMBROBBERIESOFTHETWENTIETHEGYPTIANDYNASTY/page/n21/mode/2up) references that directly

> The **tombs** and chambers in which rest the blessed

and transcribes the word as *mꜤḥꜤt*. Dickson's *Dictionary of Middle Egyptian* has an entry that (somehow) matches that:

[image]

The transliteration there matches the [Manual de Codage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_de_Codage), but where Peet uses three letters *ꜤḥꜤ*, Dickson has one hieroglyph `P6`, which according to the phonology index at the start of the dictionary should be written as *aHa*. Why he adds a *m* in front without a parallel in his hieroglyphs, I do not know.

Comparing that to the papyrus, I can identify [`P6`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/10166) as the *third* grapheme. (atop [`D36`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/9879)?) The first two and the two after that remain unclear to me; the [`X1`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/10311) (pronounced t) is probably that little dot on top of the [`O1`](https://aku-pal.uni-mainz.de/signs/10610), a sign that describes a building. The last is the plural sign, as above.

Comment: Nice work. (I had about half a day in before I gave up and wrote up what I had) Peet spends a [couple of pages](https://archive.org/details/THEGREATTOMBROBBERIESOFTHETWENTIETHEGYPTIANDYNASTY/page/n21/mode/2up?q=tomb) on terms for tomb. Its highly contextual.

Comment: @justCal and not easy to read, as he uses the phonetic transliteration from Gardiner, which are far from unambigous, not the MdC codes (which did not exist at his time).

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes what might appear to be a simple vocabulary questions leads to an interesting piece of history. In this case the query leads to a primary source, an Egyptian papyrus describing court proceedings against tomb robbers during Egypt's Twentieth Dynasty: [The Abbott Papyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbott_Papyrus)

> The Abbott Papyrus serves as an important political document
> concerning the tomb robberies of the Twentieth Dynasty of Egypt during
> the New Kingdom. It also gives insight into the scandal between the
> two rivals Pawero and Paser of Thebes.

This item is held today by the British Museum, which unfortunately seems to still be having technical difficulties. ([WebArchive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150402033524/https://www.britishmuseum.org/explore/highlights/highlight_objects/aes/t/the_abbott_papyrus.aspx)). Fortunately however, there is a publication from 1930 by [T.E. Peet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._Eric_Peet) entitled *[The Great Tomb Robberies of the Twentieth Egyptian Dynasty](https://archive.org/details/THEGREATTOMBROBBERIESOFTHETWENTIETHEGYPTIANDYNASTY/page/n3/mode/2up)* which we are free to peruse at archive.org.

Peet's translations offer a fascinating glimpse into into the people and proceedings of this time frame, as well as the complexities involved in translating a papyrus written in [Hieratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieratic).

At this point, however, I have been unable to find a point where he directly references a translation to the word thief or robber. But its still a great read for an author to gain some historical insight into the time.

---

A couple of other resources do however offer some possible translations. I was unable to get the link offered by @BrianZ in comments to function, but did find a copy of  Dickson's [Dictionary of Middle Egyptian](https://archive.org/details/DictionaryOfMiddleEgyptian/page/n3/mode/2up?q=thief) on Archive.org.

You will get 2 hits under the word *[thief](https://archive.org/details/DictionaryOfMiddleEgyptian/page/n115/mode/2up?q=thief)*,

[image]

and

[image]

(and six more by searching for *[robber](https://archive.org/details/DictionaryOfMiddleEgyptian/page/n115/mode/2up?q=robber)*  )

---

Another source is the pdf [An Egyptian hieroglyphic dictionary](https://www.um.es/cepoat/egipcio/wp-content/uploads/egyptianhierogly.pdf) which shows a couple of translations  for thief, robber or plunderer (along with representative words including vowels):

[image]
and
[image]

(again you will get 15 more hits searching for the word robber.)

So not being an expert in Egyptian linguistics, the best I can offer would be the words ***haqu*** or ***athau***. The actual correct term is likely to be highly dependent on context, but that gets more into the venue of a linguist, which I am not.

Comment: The best bet would probably be the examination of [EA 10068-1](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/Y_EA10068-1) and [EA 10068-2](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/Y_EA10068-2), which is described in Group III in Peet's book. This papyrus contains lists of thives, all starting with "Found in possession of the thief". I admit to difficulties matching description to images; at least one of them is standing on its head it seems.

Comment: [EA 10052-1](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/Y_EA10052-1) has a filing docket (right hand of the back side, turn 90° counter-clockwise) he translates as "The examination of the thieves.", repeated also in the first sentence of the front side. The script is very cursive, though. Being no expert on hieratic, I cannot make out most of the glyphs.

Comment: Yes,his book is full of locations he mentions the word, but never shows his translation in that context. The last couple of pages are an [index to phrases](https://archive.org/details/THEGREATTOMBROBBERIESOFTHETWENTIETHEGYPTIANDYNASTY/page/n199/mode/2up),  but the closest I see there is the word plunder in a couple of locations.